# Modal popup vanishes on postback

Tags: asp.net, ajax, modalpopup

I'm using a ModalPopupExtender:

```
<ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="dummyButton2" PopupControlID="DayEntryPanel" CancelControlID="Button3" BackgroundCssClass="backCSS"/>
```

Whenever I click the div that opens this, it opens for a second or two, then vanishes along with the postback.

This is opened by a javascript function that does

```
            document.getElementById("dummyButton2").click();
```

I'm sure that's the problem, but I'd really like to keep this basic logic and I'm not sure why this causes the problem. I've tried putting dummyButton2 and the extender in its own update panel with no change.

I could do something crazy like keep a variable to determine if I should be showing the popup and show it on page_load if that variable is true, but that seems like I'm going around the problem more than anything. Thoughts?

Comment: you want to show modal on page load

Answer (score 1):

See the aspx section,

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return Clicked()" /> //On this button click the popup appears.
     <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
   <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1"  runat="server" 
                            PopupControlID="popupPanel"  TargetControlID="HiddenField1" BackgroundCssClass="ModClass"
                            OkControlID="button2" CancelControlID="button3" BehaviorID="mdlpop">
    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>

   <asp:panel id="popuppanel" runat="server" style="display:none; width:200px; background-color:yellow; padding:20px;">
        <p>are you sure?</p>
        <asp:button id="button2" runat="server" text="ok" OnClientClick="Button1_Click()"   />
        <asp:button id="button3" runat="server" text="cancel" />
    </asp:panel>
```

Javascript section called by button2:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function Clicked()
    {                   
         $find('mdlpop').show(); //mdlpop is the BehaviorID in ModalPopupExtender1

          return false;      
    } 
    function Button1_Click()
    {
        alert("ok is pressed");
    }   

</script>
```

****NOTE:****Then set the cancel button id as **CancelControlID** of ModalPopupExtender1, which will automatically removes the popup on cancel button click. Also set the **PopupControlID** of the ModalPopupExtender1 to the id of your popup control (here it is popuppanel).Also the **targetcontrolID** can't be kept blank, so just added a hidden field and gave its ID there(No other significance for this).You can also set **OkControlID** (here it is set to button2) and define the operation on its clientside function.

HOpe this will help ypu to sort out the issue...

Answer (score 0):

that's not really a good idea to show your popup , do the below

```
<ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="dummyButton2" PopupControlID="DayEntryPanel" CancelControlID="Button3" BehaviourId="mpcPopup" BackgroundCssClass="backCSS"/>
```

see i provided a beahviour Id, now you can do the below

```
$find("mpcPopup").show()//show me some popup's
```

hide the popup

```
$find("mpcPopup").hide();//zoot bye
```